# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined en jvectormaps

Tags: javascript, html, brackets

Estoy usando `jvectormap` para crear un mapa interactivo con `svg` en línea, para el mapa uso un archivo `json` para cargar marcas. El problema es que al abrir el `html` no se muestra el mapa y en consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js:2 

  at jvm.Map.getMarkerPosition (jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js:2)

  at jvm.Map.createMarkers (jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js:2)

  at new jvm.Map (jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.$.fn.vectorMap (jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js:1)
    at Mexico.html:21
```

**A continuación, el código `html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>Prueba</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./jvectormap.mexico.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src = "./markers.json"> </script>     
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="world-map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
</div>
</body> 
<script>
var jsonData; function reqListener () { jsonData = JSON.toString(this.responseText); console.log(jsonData); }; var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); oReq.onload = reqListener; oReq.open("get", "markers.json", true); oReq.send();
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
map: 'Mexico',
backgroundColor: '#b3d1ff',
series: {
    regions: [{
            values: {"c0": "1", "c1": "2"},
            scale: ['#d9d4ca', '#b3d1ff'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'

        }]

},
    regionStyle: {
    initial: {
        fill: "#f4f3f0",
        stroke: "#666666",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "stroke-opacity": 1
    },
    hover: {
        fill: "#faa432",
        "fill-opacity": "1"

    }

},
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: '#F8E23B',
    stroke: '#383f47'
  }},
       markers: jsonData

})
 </script></html>
```

**Aquí el archivo `json`:**

```
[{
    "coords": [520, 360],
    "name": "2 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [530, 360],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [570, 330],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [620, 310],
    "name": "2 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [620, 325],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [410, 345],
    "name": "1 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [370, 330],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [270, 310],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [280, 310],
    "name": "1 Senior",
    "style": {"fill": "orange"}
},
{
    "coords": [340, 300],
    "name": "2 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [255, 270],
    "name": "1 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [360, 270],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [360, 200],
    "name": "2 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coord": [220, 100],
    "name": "2 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [230, 100],
    "name": "1 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
}
]
```

Comment: Funciona sin problema

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar